# Using regex lookarounds to match numbers

Tags: regex

Given the string

```
k573*A*B - k573418 + k27 * B + k2
```

What would be the regex to match "k573" but not the "k573418". I'm trying to use negative lookarounds but haven't figured it out yet.

This regex does not work:

```
k573(?!=\d)
```

as it will match both `k573`s

Any suggestions?

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/Ezj2Kr/1. BTW, `(?!=\d)` only fails the match if it finds `=` and then a digit. You probably meant `(?!\d)`

Comment: Oops. I did indeed. But the word boundary solution is actually a better solution anyway. Thanks for pointing that out.